# Blob field sets to null automatically though data present in statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

There are two inserts into table where one column is Blob. In first insert the blob stores correctly while in 2nd insert for it stores null while debuging it shows blobnullbinder where previous one shows blobbinder for the same field. This insert is happening in for loop for two times where other fields in the table varies but blob is same.I debuged before setting to CallableStatement & it is printing the value two times but in db 2nd time sets null. Why it behaves like this.

```
if (paramValue instanceof InputStream)
    ((CallableStatement) stmt).setBlob(i + 1, (InputStream) paramValue);
```

Comment: Convert the paramValue into a byte[] and set it?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `paramValue`'s `InputStream` the **same** object across the two calls?

In this case We can safely assume that when the second iteration starts, the stream will be already consumed, hence the null value.

Since the `InputStream` can't be consumed more than one time, you need to cache its contents. I suggest to read all the stream's content into a `byte []`, pass it to your method and modify your code as below:

```
if (paramValue instanceof byte[])
   ((CallableStatement) stmt).setBlob(i + 1, new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) paramValue));
```

Comment: Yes...in 2nd iteration same value.As you mentioned it will be already consumed can you please explain bit clear and how to resolve it.